# Finding frequency of range of numbers in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a list of numbers in Mathematica, how would I extract from that list the total number of numbers between numbers `a` and `b` that I specify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most direct way is simply:

```
Count[data, x_ /; a <= x <= b]
```

There are however much faster ways for most data, this one thanks to Carl Woll:

```
Tr@Unitize@Clip[data, {a, b}, {0, 0}]
```

---

Carl Woll's method is particularly fast, but as yoda pointed out, it fails if your list contains zeros, and your range also straddles zero.  Here is another method from Kevin J. McCann that handles this case, and is still very fast:

```
Tr@UnitStep[(data - a)*(b - data)]
```

As a pure function [data, a, b]:

```
Tr@UnitStep[(#-#2)*(#3-#)]&
```

Comment: Wizard: Ah, so that's what you need to do with `Count`. I tried giving it a pattern like for `Cases` and it wouldn't oblige.

Comment: Wizard: The second approach will not work when 0 is in your range.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach that you can try:

```
freq[a_, b_, list_] := Total@Boole@Cases[list, x_ :> a <= x <= b]
lst = RandomInteger[10, 20]
Out = {6, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 10, 0, 2, 10, 3, 5, 9, 1, 5, 5, 3, 8, 2, 3}

freq[3, 6, lst]
Out = 9
```

An alternate approach using `IntervalMemberQ` is

```
freq[a_, b_, list_] :=
 Total@Boole@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{a, b}], list]
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach is

```
NumberOfNumbers[lst_?ListQ, lwr_?NumberQ, upr_?NumberQ] := 
 Length@Select[lst, (lwr <= # <= upr) &]
```

D

Answer (score 1):

Please look into [`BinCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinCounts.html):

```
In[176]:= BinCounts[Range[30], {{2, 11/2}}]

Out[176]= {4}
```

Compare with direct count:

```
In[177]:= Count[Range[30], x_ /; 2 <= x < 11/2]

Out[177]= 4
```

Comment: Sasha, in Mathematica 7 BinCounts is very slow.  Has this been improved recently?

Comment: Timings on a list of 5 million reals:  `Count` = 3.234 Seconds; `BinCounts` = 39.344 Seconds; `Clip` = 0.078 Second

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `BinCounts` improved in v8, yet still looses to `Count` by a factor of 2 in timing.

Comment: I recoded `BinCounts` and `DigitCount` to be faster.  It surprised me that these were not better optimized.  I am glad to hear that has been addressed now.  Also, pardon me for not upvoting this answer, but I cannot see the advantage to `BinCounts` at this time.