# Map all values in list != to 2, to 0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a mathematica list in which I want to replace all 2s with 1 and everything else to 0.

For example.

```
{0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,2,2,6}
```

->

```
{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}
```

I assume it's possible using replace all, but what rules would achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can map the function `(Boole[2 == #]) &` onto the list.

```
In[2]:= (Boole[2 == #]) & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6}
Out[2]= {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
```

Explanation of the different parts:

- [`/@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) applies a function to each element on the list.
- The `() &` is the syntax used for [anonymous functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), and the parameter the function takes is given the name `#`.
- The [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Boole.html) converts `True`/`False` to `1`/`0`.

So, in total, we create an anonymous function, which compares its input to `2`, and gives either `0` or `1`. This function is then mapped onto the list.

Comment: I've seen this "mystical ampersand" in my mathematica travels. Could you explain what it does?

Comment: @VolatileStorm: It just creates a function. In this case, the function could just as well be defined as: `isTwo[n_] := Boole[2 == n];`, and then we could replace `(Boole[2 == #]) &` with `isTwo` in the example above.

Comment: Rather than `()&`, it's the `#-&` pair that's used for pure functions.  The `()` just sets precedence of execution and in this case, would run fine without it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Replace[{0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6}, {2 -> 1, _ -> 0}, 1]
```

I used `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` to be able to tell Mathematica at which *"level"* the replacement must take place (the last argument of `Replace`)

Comment: But `MatchQ[{0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6}, _]` returns `True`, does it not?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I corrected it right after the incorrect post, but SO appears to be a bit slow to deliver the newest version to all viewers.

Answer (score 3):

If your list is numeric, I recommend this:

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6};

1 - Unitize[2 - a]
```

---

Since timing data has been introduced in the answers, I shall add my own data points.

In order of appearance.  With Mathematica 7 on Windows 7.

First, with sparse matches (twos):

```
In[1]:=
data = RandomInteger[{0, 40000}, 150000];
(Boole[2 == #]) & /@ data // timeAvg
Replace[data, {2 -> 1, _ -> 0}, 1] // timeAvg
1 - Unitize[2 - data] // timeAvg
KroneckerDelta /@ (data - 2) // timeAvg
Unitize@Clip[data, {2, 2}, {0, 0}] // timeAvg

Out[2]= 0.0654

Out[3]= 0.01684

Out[4]= 0.0010224

Out[5]= 0.106

Out[6]= 0.00026944
```

And with dense matches:

```
In[1]:=
data = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, 150000];
(Boole[2 == #]) & /@ data // timeAvg
Replace[data, {2 -> 1, _ -> 0}, 1] // timeAvg
1 - Unitize[2 - data] // timeAvg
KroneckerDelta /@ (data - 2) // timeAvg
Unitize@Clip[data, {2, 2}, {0, 0}] // timeAvg

Out[2]= 0.0656

Out[3]= 0.01308

Out[4]= 0.0013968

Out[5]= 0.0842

Out[6]= 0.000648
```

Comment: This is nice because Unitize uses PossibleZeroQ for comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,2,2,6}/.{2->1,(x_/;MemberQ[Range[0,9],x])->0}
```

which takes advantage of the following property of `ReplaceAll`:

```
The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; 
no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts.
```

This allows for quite a bit of flexibility (eg `Range[]` may be changed to anything else).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun...

```
$v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6};

KroneckerDelta /@ ($v - 2)

(* returns {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this

```
lst={0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,2,2,6};
Clip[
    lst,
    {2,2},
    {0,0}
]
```

which is around 100 times faster than all the others, except Szabolcs', from which it is 7 times faster.

```
Timing[Do[Clip[lst, {2, 2}, {0, 0}];, {10000}]]
{0.021858, Null}

Timing[Do[KroneckerDelta /@ (lst - 2), {10000}]]  
{0.131487, Null}

Timing[Do[1 - Unitize[2 - lst], {10000}];]    
{0.214324, Null}

Timing[Do[
  lst /. {2 -> 1, (x_ /; MemberQ[Range[0, 9], x]) -> 0};, {10000}]]   
{0.533773, Null}

Timing[Do[Replace[lst, {2 -> 1, _ -> 0}, 1];, {10000}]]   
{0.066136, Null}
```

Comment: hope you don't mind my adding the timing results to your answer

Comment: @Verbeia not at all. I get randomly different timings. let me see

Comment: For what it's worth, these timings were done on a two-year-old Macbook Pro, 2.5GHz.

Comment: The question requests that all twos be replaced with ones.  Please correct this.  Otherwise, `Clip` is a good choice that I had passed by.  After [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026827/finding-frequency-of-range-of-numbers-in-mathematica/6027120#6027120) I was avoiding it for that particular use, due to a failing, but it is good here.  It is however **not** 100 times faster, but less than 10X as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake, you can also roll your own transformation function:

```
In[1]:= TwoToOne[2] = 1; TwoToOne[_] = 0;
In[2]:= Map[TwoToOne, {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6}]
Out[2]:= {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
```